# GroovyWS WSClient Preemptive Basic authentication

Tags: grails, groovy, basic-authentication, groovyws

I cannot set preemptive authentication in groovyws. (ws provider required preemptive authentication.)

I try to find out in groovyws [document](http://groovy.codehaus.org/WSClient+configuration) but no clue.

```
import groovyx.net.ws.WSClient

//def proxy = new WSClient("http://202.44.4.97/webservice/pttinfo.asmx?wsdl", this.class.classLoader)
def proxy = new WSClient("http://192.168.3.69/provider/myService", this.class.classLoader)
proxy.setBasicAuthentication('user', 'pass')

proxy.initialize()
```

below is an error.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://192.168.3.69/provider/myService
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [`groovy-wslite`](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite)? It says [in the documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS) for GroovyWS that:

> Due to low availability the project is currently dormant, you might consider groovy-wslite as a replacement module

So afaics, this should get close (I'm assuming you're [using SOAP](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite#soap)):

```
import wslite.soap.*
def client = new SOAPClient('http://192.168.3.69/provider/myService')
client.authorization = new HTTPBasicAuthorization( 'user', 'pass' )
```

There are [instructions for getting wslite working with Grails here](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite#using-with-grails).

Comment: tomorrow I'll check its again (cannot try its now because my intranet problem)